# Cisco ASA fails to handle service objects with special characters after creation

Tags: networking, firewall, bittorrent, acl

### Issue

I have the two ASAs, which are listed in the Meta section. On those devices, I configured ACLs (both devices) and PAT (5506-X only) for a device to be able to perform peer-to-peer file sharing (for different kinds of Debian derivatives) via torrent networks. As I use µTorrent to perform file sharing and I was in a hurry I named the related service object `µTorrent-port` using the ASDM. The problem is that I cannot change or delete the ACL referencing this service (see section Results). The service object itself cannot be renamed either and cannot be deleted as it is in use by the ACL.

I now want to get rid of these service objects but I cannot. I have tried to find some way to escape /encode characters inside the CLI but I had no success. The ultimate way to get rid of these objects would be to save the configuration and reset the devices to factory defaults. I would really not like to go down that path if possible.

**UPDATE:**

Of course resetting the devices to factory defaults would overshoot the target. As pointed out in the [Cisco support forum](https://community.cisco.com/t5/routing/modify-startup-config-while-using-running-config/m-p/1775915/highlight/true#M173808) one could simply transfer the config using any kind of transportation protocol, edit the file *offline* and retransfer it back to the ASA in question.
So something like

1. `copy running-config tftp:`
2. cut off the **µ** from the service object name and all its references
3. `copy tftp: running-config`

This approach dramatically reduces the downtime as opposed to a factory reset and seems easier as certificates etc. are not to be exported by default. Nevertheless, I do not really feel satisfied not being able to alter the service object name at its own.

### Meta

The issue has occured on the following devices

- Cisco ASA 5505 with ASA 9.2(4)27 and ASDM 7.9(2)
- Cisco ASA 5506-X with ASA 9.9(2) and ASDM 7.9(2)

### Results

**ASDM on 5506-X**

`no access-list outside_access_in line 3 extended permit object µtorrent-port any object torrent-pc`

```
[ERROR] no access-list outside_access_in line 3 extended permit object µtorrent-port any object torrent-pc 

no access-list outside_access_in line 3 extended permit object Âµtorrent-port 
any object torrent-pc 
^
ERROR: % Invalid input detected at '^' marker.
```

---

`object service µtorrent-port rename torrent-port`

```
[ERROR] object service µtorrent-port rename torrent-port
 object (Âµtorrent-port) does not exist.
```

---

**ASDM on 5505**

`no access-list AUTHORIZED_access_in line 13 extended permit object µtorrent any object PC-Torrent`

```
[ERROR] no access-list AUTHORIZED_access_in line 13 extended permit object µtorrent any object PC-Torrent 

no access-list AUTHORIZED_access_in line 13 extended permit object Âµtorrent a                                                                               
^ny object PC-Torrent 

ERROR: % Invalid input detected at '^' marker.
```

---

`object service µtorrent rename torrent-port`

```
[ERROR] object service µtorrent rename torrent-port
 object (Âµtorrent) does not exist.
```

---

**CLI via ASDM on 5506-X**

`no access-list outside_access_in line 3 extended permit object µtorrent-port any object torrent-pc`

```
Result of the command: "no access-list outside_access_in line 3 extended permit object µtorrent-port any object torrent-pc"

no access-list outside_access_in line 3 extended permit object Âµtorrent-port 
any object torrent-pc
^
ERROR: % Invalid input detected at '^' marker.
```

---

`object service µtorrent-port rename torrent-port`

```
Result of the command: "object service µtorrent-port rename torrent-port"

ERROR: object (Âµtorrent-port) does not exist.
```

---

**CLI via ASDM on 5505**

`no access-list AUTHORIZED_access_in line 13 extended permit object µtorrent any object PC-Torrent`

```
Result of the command: "no access-list AUTHORIZED_access_in line 13 extended permit object µtorrent any object PC-Torrent"

no access-list AUTHORIZED_access_in line 13 extended permit object Âµtorrent a                                                                               
^ny object PC-Torrent

ERROR: % Invalid input detected at '^' marker.
```

---

`object service µtorrent rename torrent-port`

```
Result of the command: "object service µtorrent rename torrent-port"

ERROR: object (Âµtorrent) does not exist.
```

Comment: A thought: is there any wildcard support that may help? Something like `object service *torrent rename torrent-port`.

Comment: AFAIK, there is no way of doing regex with ACLs or objects. I know regex works with `include`, `exclude` etc. as well as with the selection of interfaces. I have tried your idea with some well-known regex non-literals but it does not work, the ASA takes the characters literally.